# Extract nested json map

Tags: groovy

Have JSON received from some REST API:

```
{
   "advertiser_id": {
      "8253":{
         "name":"Signify",
         "id":8253
      },
      "2920":{
         "name":"Hyundai",
         "id":2920
      }
   }
}
```

I wan't to extract maps inside numbers like `8253`, `2920` but without hard mapping these numbers, they can be different at any time. Anyway these numbers just duplicates `id` inside.

Expected output after transformation:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Signify",
      "id":8253
   },
   {
      "name":"Hyundai",
      "id":2920
   }
]
```

Tried with:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = '''
'''

def p = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def result = p["advertiser_id"].collectEntries{ k, v ->
    [
            id: v.id,
            name: v.name
    ]
}
```

But it returns only one "object":

```
{
    "id": 8905,
    "name": "Spotify"
}
```

Also achieved wrong result with next code:

```
def a = p["advertiser_id"].collectMany {
    it.value.collect{ k, v ->
        [
                id: k,
                name: v
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to build a list - so you need `collect` instead of `collectEntries`

```
def p = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def result = p["advertiser_id"].collect{ k, v -> 
    [
        id: v.id,
        name: v.name
    ]
}
```

and you are not doing any transformation to nested objects - so, you could simplify the code to this:

```
def result = p.advertiser_id.collect{ k, v -> v }
```